# kNN Estimation with Sparse Matrices in Python using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, knn

I have data that looks like this:

```
line1 = '-0.9821 1:15 2:20 4:10 8:10'
line2 = '0.1235 1:15 2:20 6:10 10:10'
line3 = '0.2132 1:15 3:20 5:10 9:10'
line4 = '0.328 2:15 4:20 6:10 7:12 8:16 10:10'
line5 = '0.973 2:15 3:20 6:10 8:12 9:10'
```

The first entry in each line is the output (Y) variable.  The remaining entries represent sparse vectors (e.g., '1:15' means that at index 1, the X value is 15).

I am trying to calculate a predicted Y based on kNN estimation.  I'm new to sparse matrices.  I found some documentation that says I can use sparse matrices to estimate kNN:

```
knn = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2, weights='distance')
knn.fit(X, Y)
```

I am not sure how to create the X and Y matrices, and then how to predict Y given the kNN estimation. Any help for a beginner like me would be much appreciated.

Comment: That function you're suggesting to use [seems to be](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) from [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html). Are solutions required to use that library, or are you open for others, too? If the question is related to that library, consider adding the `scikit-learn` tag.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, that the sparse vectors represent the (n-dimensional) inputs X to an unknown process and the Y scalars the resulting output, each "line" representing one output/input pair? And you'd like to use them to estimate the output Y for other, future inputs X?

Comment: @das-g yes, each line represents one output/input pair.  I'm using the SVM-Light package at http://svmlight.joachims.org/ and I need to estimate the epsilon and c parameters to input into the SVM program.  The epsilon parameter requires an estimate for Y using the k nearest neighbors of the training set.  Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Why do you think you should use kNN? This seems to be a regression task and not a classification one. Have you considered something like a Logistic Regression instead? Also, is that actual data or just an example, because if that's the actual data then it's not sparse and seems to have 30-50% coverage

Comment: @SlaterTyranus, I can't use logistic regression because the number of independent variables is MUCH larger than the number of observations.  Support vector regression is what I'm trying to do.  With SVR, you have to estimate parameters epsilon and c to put into the model.  Also, this is not actual data.  Just an example.  The actual data is much more sparse.

Comment: @myname, Sorry, now I'm confused, are you trying kNN or SVR here? Can you also post some specifics about the data you're working with? Logistic/Ridge regression is typically the goto for many independent variables for computational efficiency if nothing else.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus, support vector regression requires an input parameter for epsilon.  Epsilon is calculated with kNN estimation as the variance between the actual output and the predicted output using, say, the 5 nearest neighbors.  So, to be able to run SVR, I need to first estimate kNN.  The data has about 70,000 output overvations (Y) and over 300,000 independent variables (X).  Logistic regression would not work with this kind of data because there are not sufficient degrees of freedom.

Comment: @myname You don't need to calculate epsilon that way. Using an approximate value will be more than sufficient. Also `sklearn` takes care of it for you, looks at the docs: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html. Also, I understand the space and the library quite well, please don't feel the need to explain everything to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short is that the format you're using is going to cause you a decent amount of grief. The long is that it's still absolutely possible to do this conversion, there's just a decent amount of goo-code that you're going to need. The first thing you're going to need to do is split each string on the first occurrence of space, and group the rest into x.

```
from scipy import sparse

y, _, x = line1.partition(" ")
y = float(y)
x = convert_to_csc(x, shape)

def convert_to_csc(x, shape):
    sparse_matrix = sparse.csc_matrix(shape)
    for entry in x.split():
        index, value = entry.split(:)
        sparse_matrix[index] = value
    return sparse_matrix
```

I'll leave the rest as an exercise to the reader, but the rest should be pretty trivial. If you have the chance later on I would suggest relying on a more robust format.

To make it clear, aggregating the `x`'s and `y`'s in this example will give you the `X`, and `Y` in your code above. As far as getting the prediction out afterward, `sklearn` uses the `fit_transform` paradigm, meaning first you `fit`, then you `transform`. After you call fit above, you can get a prediction like so:

```
prediction = knn.transform(example_x)
```

I still think you should look into using `sklearn`'s SVR natively. I'd also highly suggest trying another model. Logistic Regression probably won't give you better performance than SVR in this case (though I could be wrong), but it would serve as an excellent testbed for any augmentations or general data tweaks you're thinking of adding, if for not reason other than the computational efficiency. SVR on the dataset you're talking about is... not going to run quickly.

Comment: There is also sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_format which is a fast and robust implementation of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the info Andreas! I was totally unaware of that, though it appears the name is technically load_svmlight_file

Answer (score 0):

use a sparse array to store the data.  Parse the string values into the sparse array then fit and predict on the knn

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

line1 = '-0.9821 1:15 2:20 4:10 8:10'
line2 = '0.1235 1:15 2:20 6:10 10:10'
line3 = '0.2132 1:15 3:20 5:10 9:10'
line4 = '0.328 2:15 4:20 6:10 7:12 8:16 10:10'
line5 = '0.973 2:15 3:20 6:10 8:12 9:10'

data=[line1,line2,line3,line4,line5]

sparseMatrix = csr_matrix((5, 15), 
                      dtype = np.float).toarray()
row=0
for item in data:
    for entry in item.split(' '):
        if ':' in entry:
            index,value = entry.split(':')
            sparseMatrix[row,int(index)]=value
        else:
            sparseMatrix[row,0]=entry
    row+=1


X=sparseMatrix[:,1:15]
y=(sparseMatrix[:,0]*10).astype(int)

knn=KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto',
                     leaf_size=10,
                     metric='minkowski',
                     metric_params=None,
                     n_jobs=1,
                     n_neighbors=3,
                     p=2,
                     weights='uniform')

 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=21)
knn.fit(X_train,y_train)

train_accuracy = knn.score(X_train, y_train)
test_accuracy=knn.score(X_test,y_test)
print(train_accuracy,test_accuracy)

for item in X:
   prediction=knn.predict([item])
   print(item,prediction)

y_pred=knn.predict(X_test)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
```

output:

```
 0.25 0.0
 [15. 20.  0. 10.  0.  0.  0. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.] [-9]
 [15. 20.  0.  0.  0. 10.  0.  0.  0. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0.] [-9]
 [15.  0. 20.  0. 10.  0.  0.  0. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.] [-9]
 [ 0. 15.  0. 20.  0. 10. 12. 16.  0. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0.] [-9]
 [ 0. 15. 20.  0.  0. 10.  0. 12. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.] [-9]
```